# Rename file on FTP with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ftp, rename, webclient

Is there a way to rename the file in a FTP directory?
I'm streaming live images from computer to FTP, but problem is that when it uploads the image to FTP it making instant replacement of a file. I want to firstly upload image with temporary name and then make a rename to live.jpg. It's gonna be like cached file uploading.

```
while($true)
{
    $i++
    $File = "c:\live\temp.jpg"
    $ftp = "ftp://username:password@example.com/camera/temp.jpg"

    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $File)
}
```

How can I use this in script properly ?

```
Rename-Item ..\camera\temp.jpg live.jpg
```

Thanx!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("ftp://username:password@example.com/camera/temp.jpg")
$ftp.KeepAlive = $true
$ftp.UsePassive = $true
$ftp.Method = "Rename"
$ftp.RenameTo = "camera/temp1.jpg"
$ftp.UseBinary = $true
$response = [System.Net.FtpWebResponse] $ftp.GetResponse()
```

Comment: `UsePassive` and `UseBinary` properties have no effect on the `Rename` method and they are `$true` by default anyway. The `KeepAlive` is also `$true` by default. So all three can be removed without any effect on the code result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("ftp://username:password@example.com/camera/temp.jpg")
$ftp.KeepAlive = $true
$ftp.UsePassive = $true
$ftp.Method = "Rename"
$ftp.RenameTo = "camera/temp1.jpg"
$ftp.UseBinary = $true
$response = [System.Net.FtpWebResponse] $ftp.GetResponse()
```

I had to adjust the $ftp.RenameTo line and remove the directory to make it work for me:

```
$ftp.RenameTo = "temp1.jpg"
```

Thanks anyway

Comment: I think that's expected because the current directory is set to /camera.  See further explanation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?view=net-5.0) ... **under the 'Remarks' section**:

`The URI may be relative or absolute. If the URI is of the form "ftp://contoso.com/path", first the .NET Framework logs into the FTP server, then the current directory is set to <UserLoginDirectory>/path.`