# FTP Upload and REname

Tags: powershell, ftp, ftpwebrequest

OK pardon my scripting noobness, I have a PowerShell script which lookup a folder for specific files extension and upload them to a FTP site and creates a log file.

This works well but there is a new requirement to rename the files extension after the upload.
I understand that I need to use WebRequest instead of WebClient but I am struggling with it. How can I achieve this?
Here is the current script:

```
$LogFile='C:\test\log.txt'

$TimeStamp= get-date -Format yyyyMMdd"_"HHmmss
$ScriptrunTime= get-date 

Add-Content $LogFile ' '
Add-Content $LogFile '------------------------------------------------------'

Add-Content $LogFile ' '

$msg= '-----------   Script run time: ' + $TimeStamp +'     -----------'
Add-Content $LogFile $msg

Add-Content $LogFile ' '

$FTP="ftp://username:password@ftp.site/folder/"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 

$webclient.Proxy = [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy

$Source ='C:\source'

try{

$data = @(dir  -file $Source\*.tmp | select fullname, name)

$msg='Source: ' + $Source
Add-Content $LogFile $msg

Add-Content $LogFile ' '
$msg='Target: ' + $FTP
Add-Content $LogFile $msg

Add-Content $LogFile ' '
$msg='There are ' + $data.Count + ' files to upload'
Add-Content $LogFile $msg

foreach($item in $data){


Add-Content $LogFile ' '

$UploadFile=$ftp+$item.Name
$UploadFileName=$item.FullName


try
{
    $msg="Uploading $UploadFile"
    Add-Content $LogFile $msg

     $webclient.UploadFile($UploadFile, $UploadFileName)


    Add-Content $LogFile ' '
    Add-Content $LogFile "Upload completed"

    Add-Content $LogFile ' '

    Add-Content $LogFile ' '
    Add-Content $LogFile "Delete file"



    }
    catch
    {
    $ErrorDesc=$_.Exception.Message

    Add-Content $LogFile ' '
    $msg='Error occured: '+ $ErrorDesc
    Add-Content $LogFile $msg
}

Add-Content $LogFile ' '

}
}
catch
{

$ErrorDesc=$_.Exception.Message
Add-Content $LogFile ' '
$msg='Error occured: '+ $ErrorDesc
Add-Content $LogFile $msg
}

$TimeStamp= get-date -Format yyyyMMdd"_"HHmmss
$ScriptrunTime= get-date 
Add-Content $LogFile ' '
$msg='-----------   Script end time: ' + $TimeStamp +'     -----------'
Add-Content $LogFile $msg
```

Comment: Could you not rename the file before the upload with move-item, move it to a staging area (at the same time), upload the newly renamed file, then delete all in the staging area?

Comment: Why dont you just change the extension before the upload to FTP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename file on FTP with PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070808/rename-file-on-ftp-with-powershell)

Comment: This was the original requirement which was silly but I negotiated than the guys on the other side do the renaming themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebClient.UploadFile` method doesn't require that the `address` and `fileName` parameters refer to a file of the same name. So you could change the extension of the file as you upload it. Assuming the new extension is `ext`:

```
$UploadFile = $ftp + [IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($item.Name, "ext");

$webclient.UploadFile($UploadFile, $UploadFileName);
```