# Rename file on FTP using Powershell - (553) File name not allowed

Tags: powershell, ftp

I have a script which uploads a file on a FTP server. I want to mark the success of my FTP upload process by renaming the file and adding a `"_complete"` at the end of the filename.

I did look for answers and I have followed the steps in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070808/rename-file-on-ftp-with-powershell) in order to rename the file, but I get an error at the last line.

Below is 90% of the script (except the part where I initialize values, user, pass, ftp address etc.)

```
# Destination filename
$destination_filename = $ftp_addr+$backup_source_app_data.BaseName+"_"+$script_start_time.hour+"-"+$script_start_time.minute+"-"+$script_start_time.second

# Initialize connection to FTP
$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($destination_filename+".zip")
$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]$ftp
$ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
$ftp.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

$ftp.Timeout = -1              #infinite timeout
$ftp.ReadWriteTimeout = -1     #infinite timeout

$ftp.UseBinary = $true
$ftp.UsePassive = $true

sz a -mx=3 $backup_target_app_data $backup_source_app_data.FullName

$requestStream = $ftp.GetRequestStream()
$fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($backup_target_app_data)
$chunk = New-Object byte[] $bufSize

while( $bytesRead = $fileStream.Read($chunk,0,$bufsize) )
{
    $requestStream.write($chunk, 0, $bytesRead)
    $requestStream.Flush()
}

$FileStream.Close()
$requestStream.Close()

$ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($destination_filename+".zip")
$ftp.KeepAlive = $true
$ftp.UsePassive = $true
$ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::Rename
$ftp.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)
$ftp.RenameTo = $destination_filename + "_complete" + ".zip"
$ftp.UseBinary = $true
$response = [System.Net.FtpWebResponse] $ftp.GetResponse()
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote
>   server returned an error: (553) File name not allowed." At
>   C:\Users\rgheorghiu\Desktop\Untitled2.ps1:75 char:61
>   +     $response = [System.Net.FtpWebResponse] $ftp.GetResponse <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

I'm not sure what I can do to get over this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes. The file is uploaded at the FTP location sucessfully, except it's not being renamed.

Comment: Ah, `RenameTo` should be relative i.e. without the `ftp://address/basepath/`

Comment: @wOxxOm So, it should be just the new filename and that's it?

Comment: @wOxxOm Golden! It worked! Thank you! Do you mind posting an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Idk what to say about that. This question is Powershell related and the accepted answer in the other question says that you're supposed to post a path, which is opposite of what the solution in this case was (because I tried a full qualified path without the ftp address).

Comment: It does not matter that this question is PowerShell and the other is C#. What matters is that the same .NET class is being used. + I do not see any code in your question *"trying a full qualified path without the ftp address"* - I see you trying FTP URL: `$destination_filename = $ftp_addr+$backup_source_app_data.BaseName+"_"+$script_start_time.hour+"-"+$script_start_time.minute+"-"+$script_start_time.second`
 - `$ftp.RenameTo = $destination_filename + "_complete" + ".zip"`