# Rename files on remote FTP using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp

Can anyone help with rename files on remote FTP server after downloading them? I have included snippet of the Powershell code currenting used to download the files.

Ideally i would like to append "_DONE" to end of the file e.g. name-of-file.pdf_DONE

I have tried issuing RenameTo method, but done understand Powershell enough to figure out the correct syntax.

```
#Set Crednetials
$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

#set folder path
$folderPath= $ftp + "/" + $folder + "/"

$files = Get-FTPDir -url $folderPath -credentials $credentials

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = $credentials 
$counter = 0
foreach ($file in ($files | where {$_ -like "*.pdf"})){
    $source = $folderPath + $file  
    $destination = $target + $file 
    $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
    
    #PRINT FILE NAME AND COUNTER
    $counter++
    $source

**#RENAME FILE**

}
```

Comment: `Rename-Item [-Path] <string> [-NewName] <string> [-Force] [-PassThru] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [-UseTransaction]  [<CommonParameters>]`

Comment: does `$destination` include the comp name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename file on FTP with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070808/rename-file-on-ftp-with-powershell)