# Renaming file extensions on FTP site using powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp

I am looking to rename some file extensions on a suppliers ftp (renaming from *.tmp to *.txt) and would like to use a powershell script so this can be run as a scheduled task.

Being a total newbie using PS I did some searching but could not find exactly what I needed.  I did find various scripts that uploaded and download the files, altering some of the code to try and get what I want but with no success due to my lack of knowledge

If anyone can assist that would be very much appreciated

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Hello! Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12075733/5720797

Comment: Hi and thanks, I would need to rename ALL files in the folder this looks like it only renames 1 file.

Comment: Yes, so use this to rename all files. We are here to help you, not do everything for you. Hints - this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059394/powershell-connect-to-ftp-server-and-get-files) topic can provide you needed information.

Comment: perfect thank you :)